# S3 files are accessible by Hadoop but not Spark

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am running Spark 1.4 along Hadoop 2.6 on a single EC2 machine.
I configured the HADOOP_CLASSPATH and core-site.xml to get access to my S3 files.

While Hadoop is able to access the files in my bucket, spark-shell fails miserably throwing the following error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found
```

I tried adding the aws jars to the classpath, but nothing helps.

Anyone has any idea where this might be coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this error occurring during spark operations or while launching spark-shell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two extra jar files into the class path

eg. in your spark-submit
--jar=aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:hadoop-aws-2.6.0.jar

or you can add into your config:
eg. spark.executor.extraClassPath & spark.driver.extraClassPath

In addition, try to use "s3a://" which is a newer S3 library in Hadoop

Comment: Don't think it works right now. A JIRA ticket is blocking this from functioning properly: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7481

Comment: what does it mean if you put just names of the jar `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar` into the `--jars` flag ?